# Is this mistake of JavaFX SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

In JavaFX SceneBuilder I wanted to style border of Pane to be only on the right side, so I put in the JavaFX CSS style box this: -fx-border-style: none solid none none , but it did whole border visible. Then I find out, that if I put "none" as a first value, the border will be allways whole.

Can someone tell me please , how to fix it, or if there's some other way to do that?

[image: JavaFX CSS view]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre]. Specifically, include an FXML file that demonstrates the issue, along with the application code to display it.

Comment: If you try to search for similar questions, there are at least two things come up that your could try: the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) says this property is comma-separated (though various other sources say it isn't), and while the documentation says `none`, some people found `hidden` working instead.

Comment: Both the implementation (doesn't work correctly if the top border is set to "none') and the documentation (does not describe sets of four values for four different sides for border-style) appear to have bugs.

Comment: @tevemadar Note the documentation says commas are used to separate values for _different borders_ (you can have multiple border e.g., strokes with different styles, widths, colors, etc. on a single region). Though the documentation fails to say anything about allowing four values for a _single border_ (for each side of the border). It's somewhat inferable from the way `BorderStroke` works and how the other `-fx-border-xxx` properties work, but that's definitely a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @Slaw obviously I haven't tried any of them, just mentioned what I've seen in somewhat similar topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is a bug in JavaFX 21 CSS border rule processing**

This appears to be a bug in CSS border handling in JavaFX 21.  It is not an issue in SceneBuilder or FXML, or the core border logic of JavaFX.

As noted by James in comments:

> Both the implementation (doesn't work correctly if the top border is set to "none') and the documentation (does not describe sets of four values for four different sides for border-style) appear to have bugs.

You might wish to [file a bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) on this.  If you do so, you can link back to this issue and add a comment to this answer (or edit it) to add a reference to the related bug report.

The issue is that, if you specify all four border styles in a CSS rule *and* the first border style is set to `none`, then the border styles do not take effect -> all borders show.

**Replicating the Issue**

The code below replicates the issue (tested on JavaFX 21).

1. The first box, is rendered incorrectly, showing all four borders when only the right border should show.

   ```
   -fx-border-style: none solid none none;
   ```
2. The second box renders correctly, the top and right borders show and the other borders do not.

   ```
   -fx-border-style: solid solid none none;
   ```
3. The third box renders correctly, only the right border shows.  However, this was implemented in code rather than CSS. As a work-around for your issue you can write your border styles in code rather than using CSS.

   ```
   Border codedBorder = new Border(
           new BorderStroke(
                   Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
                   BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE,
                   CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                   new BorderWidths(10, 8, 6, 4),
                   Insets.EMPTY
           )
   );
   ```

[image: demos]

**Example Code: BrokenBorders.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BrokenBorders extends Application {
    private static final String CSS = "data:text/css,";
    private static final String CUSTOM_BORDER_CSS = CSS + // language=CSS
            """            
            .broken-border {
                -fx-border-style: none solid none none;
                -fx-border-color: black red green blue;
                -fx-border-width: 10 8 6 4;
                -fx-background-color: lightgreen;
            }

            .working-border {
                -fx-border-style: solid solid none none;
                -fx-border-color: black red green blue;
                -fx-border-width: 10 8 6 4;
                -fx-background-color: lightblue;
            }
            
            .root {
                -fx-font-size: 40px;
            }
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createLayout()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static VBox createLayout() {
        StackPane brokenBorderedPane = new StackPane(new Label("1"));
        brokenBorderedPane.getStyleClass().add("broken-border");
        brokenBorderedPane.setPrefSize(100, 100);

        StackPane workingBorderedPane = new StackPane(new Label("2"));
        workingBorderedPane.getStyleClass().add("working-border");
        workingBorderedPane.setPrefSize(100, 100);

        StackPane codedBorderPane = new StackPane(new Label("3"));
        Border codedBorder = new Border(
                new BorderStroke(
                        Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
                        BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE,
                        CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                        new BorderWidths(10, 8, 6, 4),
                        Insets.EMPTY
                )
        );
        codedBorderPane.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.LIGHTPINK));
        codedBorderPane.setBorder(codedBorder);
        codedBorderPane.setPrefSize(100, 100);

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                brokenBorderedPane,
                workingBorderedPane,
                codedBorderPane
        );
        layout.getStylesheets().add(CUSTOM_BORDER_CSS);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        return layout;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: A workaround for the OP is to specify widths instead of styles (e.g., `-fx-border-width: 0 2 0 0;`).

Comment: Or if the widths are important to layout ([borders affect a region's insets](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#insetsProperty())), use transparent colors for the sides not meant to be seen (e.g., `-fx-border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;`)

Comment: @jewelsea in my situation is more suitable advice from Slaw or tevemadar. If I could connect it with the FXML file and continue work in SceneBuilder would by better, but still the border width/color or the "hidden" solution is way more faster. Anyway thank you all.

Comment: I tried filing a bug report for this at the recommended reporting location: [https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report), which links to [https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/start_form](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/start_form).  However, I was unable to do so, due to the following response on submitting the bug report form: `Request method 'POST' not supported`.  So I don't really know how to report this issue, perhaps it could be posted to the `openfjx-dev` mailing list.

Comment: @Jouzef While you can define styles in the FXML file, I would recommend separating out the styles into a CSS file. You can add the stylesheet to the root of the FXML file, and Scene Builder will still preview those styles. It will even watch the file for changes and update accordingly.